# JQGrid data is not loading with JSON server response

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid, response

I'm trying to load data from the `jsp` response which is a `JSON` using **JQGrid**.

my index.html

```
<pre>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqgrid/src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqgrid/src/grid.loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
</pre>

function getEmployeeDetails(){
   jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
     datatype: function(postdata) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                 url: 'execute.jsp?command=command',
                 mtype:'POST',
                 datatype:"json",
                     colModel : [
                     {name:'amount', width:30, sortable:true, align:'center'},
                     {name:'age', width:40, sortable:false, align:'center'},
                     {name:'name', width:180, sortable:true, align:'left'},
                     {name:'total', width:380, sortable:true, align:'left'}
                     ],

                   jsonReader : {
                         root: "key",
                         page: "currentpage",
                         total: "total",
                         records: "totalrecords",
                         repeatitems: true,
                         cell: "cell",
                         id: "id",
                         userdata: "userdata" 
                         }, 
                         width: 700,
                         height: 200,

                   pager: '#pager',
                   sortorder: 'desc',
                   viewrecords: true,
                   caption: 'My first grid'
            });
           }
   });
}
```

And my **execute.jsp** code

```
**<pre>
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(wr.toJSONString());
</pre>**
```

my `JSON string` generated from java object.

```
{
    "totalrecords":"20",
    "tota1":"10",
    "currentpage":"runCommand.jsp",
    "key":[
    {"id":"1","cell":["12000","30","Myname","10000"]}
    ]
}
```

Data is not loading into the table. I am trying in different ways I can't succeed. Always table is coming empty and says loading.....Please help me. What is wrong here...

Comment: You should never use both `grid.loader.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. If you need debug JavaScript code of jqGrid it would be better to use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` (and no `grid.loader.js` of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `datatype` in the wrong way. You don't need call `jQuery.ajax` manually jqGrid will make this for you. The JavaScript code could be about the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url: 'execute.jsp?command=command',
        mtype:'POST',
        datatype:"json",
        colModel : [
             {name:'amount', width:30, align:'center'},
             {name:'age', width:40, sortable:false, align:'center'},
             {name:'name', width:180},
             {name:'total', width:380}
        ],
        jsonReader : {
            root: "key",
            page: "currentpage",
            total: "total",
            records: "totalrecords"
        },
        width: 700,
        height: 200, // the value 'auto' could be probably better
        pager: '#pager',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'My first grid'
    });
});
```

See the demo [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/mathi.htm). You should correct the value `"currentpage":"runCommand.jsp"` from your JSON data to some numeric value like `"currentpage":"1"` for example.

Comment: @ Oleg. Thanks a ton for resolving this issue. You saved my days.I got it working. Thanks, thanks,thanks.

Comment: @mathi: You are welcome! I am glad to hear (to read) that I could help you much.